# how to install virtual servers with Gentoo?

Tags: virtualization

i have a server with the following specifications:
Dual Quad Core cpu
16GB Ram
6x1TB HDD

I previously had another server hosted and configured by some techs that installed with Gentoo 3 virtual servers on the same machine, they were like separate linux machines, but actually on the same one.

Can anyone tell me what guide should i follow and what software for virtual machines or whatever is more indicated for this distribution? they've said that Gentoo somehow make it easy but never got into details. DOn't know if they used Vmware or other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/KVM -

emerge -av qemu-kvm usbutils bridge-utils usermode-utilities iptables

From http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/xen-guide.xml -

emerge xen xen-tools xen-sources

Your other options are to download and install VMWare or Virtualbox.

Comment: yes i'm sure my techs configured the previous servers con XEN, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Another option based on your needs is openvz.  In our configuration we needed openvz due to some real time apps and shortcomings of XEN/VirtualBox.

OpenVZ is like a super-chroot environment and can serve very well if you aren't running many different OSes.